# How to update an existing Marketing Cloud Subscriber using the SOAP APi

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am trying to figure out how to use the SOAP API to update an existing Marketing Cloud subscriber's email address. I've tried different permutations of the below request (with Create and Update action) and although the response is successful, it does not update the record.

In the example below, my All Subscribers list as the id `52`.

Please can someone check?

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <fueloauth
            xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">77fMQroSJGVTIvmiOCxCuNWF
        </fueloauth>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:UpdateRequest>
            <Options>
                <SaveOptions>
                    <SaveOption>
                        <PropertyName>*</PropertyName>
                        <SaveAction>UpdateAdd</SaveAction>
                    </SaveOption>
                </SaveOptions>
            </Options>
            <ns1:Objects xsi:type="ns1:Subscriber">
                <ns1:Attributes>
                    <ns1:Name>EmailAddress</ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:Value>simon@sausage.com</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Attributes>
                <ns1:SubscriberKey>1234</ns1:SubscriberKey>
                <ns1:Lists>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns1:ID>52</ns1:ID>
                </ns1:Lists>
            </ns1:Objects>
        </ns1:UpdateRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with this SOAP envelope -- without specifying the Lists:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope>
   <s:Header>
      <!-- REMOVED -->
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <UpdateRequest>
         <Options>
            <Client>
               <ID><!-- MID GOES HERE --></ID>
            </Client>
            <SaveOptions>
               <SaveOption>
                  <PropertyName>*</PropertyName>
                  <SaveAction>UpdateOnly</SaveAction>
               </SaveOption>
            </SaveOptions>
         </Options>
         <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
            <Client>
               <ID><!-- MID GOES HERE --></ID>
            </Client>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
            <EmailAddress>spriggsa@digitalev.com</EmailAddress>
            <Attributes>
               <Name>Email Address</Name>
               <Value>spriggsa@digitalev.com</Value>
            </Attributes>
            <SubscriberKey>aspriggs@degdigital.com</SubscriberKey>
         </Objects>
      </UpdateRequest>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi Adam, that worked, thanks. I've simplified this somewhat as it turns out you don't necessarily require an MID (even if you have multiple BUs on the account). Here's [a gist with an updated method](https://gist.github.com/eliotharper/f29a78abba23020d8465).

Comment: @Adam Spriggs, I'm using the same SOAP envolope to update the subscriber status to "Unsubscribe", the response return OK,200 but when I see the UI it does not update the status of the subscriber. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @JiteshGoel you should [log an unsub event](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/241382/5202) if you're trying to unsubscribe a subscriber.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs , Im unsubscribing the subscriber from a Third Psrty(Salesforce in our case). How can we use from there?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update a List (or Publication List) in the Lists tag take into consideration that the ID accepts an integer, i.e. 3899 not 3899_HTML

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Create</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-6ea8039d2ea0</a:MessageID>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://<<YOUR INSTANCE>>.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">your_access_token</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
             <Options>
                <SaveOptions>
                   <SaveOption>
                      <PropertyName>*</PropertyName>
                      <SaveAction>UpdateOnly</SaveAction>
                   </SaveOption>
                </SaveOptions>
             </Options>
             <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></ObjectID>
                <SubscriberKey>XPTO</SubscriberKey>
                <EmailAddress>someemail@email.com</EmailAddress>
                <Lists>
                   <ID>3899</ID>
                   <ListClassification>PublicationList</ListClassification>
                   <Status>Active</Status>
                   <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></ObjectID>
                </Lists>
             </Objects>
        </CreateRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```