# Sales Cloud to Marketing Cloud - immediate updates on All Subscribers list

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

Currently we use Automation Studio to update subscriber data on All Subscribers list. This happens every night, but if needed I could set it to run 4x every hour as this is the interval at which my data synchronized from Sales Cloud is updated.

Now we would like to be able to update the subscriber's Email Address in MC (All Subscribers list) immediately after it gets changed in Sales Cloud. I was looking at API calls, but seems that I won't be able to use SOAP to update ListSubscriber  object (according to: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/supported_operations_for_objects_and_methods.htm).

Can you please share how to best achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you need to update using the SOAP API is the [Subscriber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/subscriber.htm) object. An example of a SOAP envelope that updates a Subscriber's email address can be viewed in [this thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/99780/how-to-update-an-existing-marketing-cloud-subscriber-using-the-soap-api).

With respect to making such a real-time call to Marketing Cloud's SOAP API from an a Apex Trigger, [here's a good post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200593/making-a-callout-in-apex-to-marketing-cloud-soap-api) to use as a starting point.

Comment: this looks great, thank you!